# Реализовать код лучше

Tags: python, matplotlib

Будучи абсолютным новичком в `matplotlib`, я, написав такой код, хочу узнать, как реализовать его лучше/компактнее:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([5,5,5,5,5], 'g--', label = 'example')
ax.plot([0,3,2,1,4], 'o-', label = 'you')

ax.tick_params(labelcolor = 'r')
ax.set_xlabel('Attempts', color = 'r')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of guessed (out of 5)', color = 'r')
ax.set(facecolor = 'black')
f.set(facecolor = 'black')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: а что именно вас не устраивает в этом коде?

Comment: Да нечего тут особо прям улучшать. Вот если у вас будет копипаста из 20 таких фрагментов, то нужно будет вынести в отдельную функцию этот код и сделать цикл. А над одним графиком нет смысла особо морочиться. Он вот разве что не читабелен, я бы белую подложку лучше сделал, например.

Comment: @strawdog Громоздкость.

Comment: Ну, таков matplotlib в принципе. Мало нарисовать график, потом его ещё нужно донастроить. Возможно, что-то из этого можно реализовать короче, но в целом я бы не заморачивался.